# Can't connect to wifi after update

Tags: wireless, 16.04, atheros

On ubuntu 16.04.
When I run `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` I get:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:383a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

As requested:

```
$ uname -a; dmesg | grep ath
Linux Yinon 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edditional edit:

```
$ sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath10k_pci': Required key not available
$ dmesg | grep ath
[    1.509368]  [<ffffffff81081212>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    1.509370]  [<ffffffff810812ac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
```

Ethernet works good.
How can I find out what is wrong?

Comment: Please add output of `uname -a; dmesg | grep ath` to your question. And also remove `wl` by `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: Added. I also removed w1, I don't know if it was supposed to resolve the problem but it didn't.

Comment: It is not `w1`, it is `wl`. See the @YinGroen answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci` and also: `dmesg | grep ath` when run *after* the modprobe.

Comment: I have added the commands you requested. @chili555

Comment: You don't need backports for this card anymore

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the general solution for `168c:0042` device issues, although it hasn't worked for me:

Update your device firmware:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

After the update, reboot and let us know the results

Comment: It didnt work for me.

Comment: Any other ideas?